# Chi-Square testing of random data flags good generator as broken

Tags: random-variables, entropy

I'm trying to statistically anayze random number generators, i.e., generators which are intended to produce truly random sequences of bytes (integers in the range [0..255]). An incredibly helpful answer on here ([Expected standard deviation of random binary data](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4287688/expected-standard-deviation-of-random-binary-data/4287741#4287741)) has pointed me in the direction of performing Chi-Square testing on data. I believe I've understood this and implemented it accordingly and can follow all calculations in there.

To test my understanding, I've first collected massive amounts of data which come from a generator that is arguably good (the CSPRNG of the Linux Kernel). I've collected rougly $250 \cdot 10^9$ bytes of data (250 GB). This is the distribution of characters:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
1010966001 & 1010976991 & 1010887488 & 1010948243 & 1010949190 & 1010934553 & 1010917522 & 1010874898 & 1010930071 & 1010980459 & 1010952497 & 1010919164 & 1011010055 & 1011037805 & 1010926897 & 1010893562\\
1010942296 & 1010977576 & 1010892288 & 1010947126 & 1010893758 & 1010891819 & 1010931300 & 1010954491 & 1010955681 & 1010941487 & 1010924343 & 1010883070 & 1010951658 & 1010965997 & 1010963238 & 1010905981\\
1010993133 & 1010953999 & 1010917479 & 1010998971 & 1010893851 & 1010941162 & 1010908262 & 1010920158 & 1010993261 & 1010931826 & 1010975359 & 1010946839 & 1011012098 & 1010916290 & 1010972240 & 1010908297\\
1010972291 & 1010987647 & 1010897830 & 1010934125 & 1010945903 & 1010964191 & 1010942402 & 1010967532 & 1010951110 & 1010925373 & 1010986320 & 1010922827 & 1010952648 & 1010953384 & 1010971172 & 1010963271\\
1010960728 & 1010905023 & 1010945309 & 1010967246 & 1010951352 & 1010918808 & 1010872008 & 1010976774 & 1010969050 & 1010905604 & 1010881371 & 1010961491 & 1010927386 & 1010923038 & 1010952101 & 1010940779\\
1010941149 & 1010983955 & 1010939022 & 1010895198 & 1010920462 & 1010932243 & 1010943817 & 1010972391 & 1010923768 & 1010906746 & 1010916839 & 1010978691 & 1010933593 & 1010943920 & 1010907036 & 1010965189\\
1010912902 & 1010924036 & 1010905632 & 1010987306 & 1010904971 & 1010937804 & 1010976976 & 1010889794 & 1010851229 & 1010946839 & 1010930434 & 1010969428 & 1010977693 & 1010926171 & 1010980490 & 1010882169\\
1010961365 & 1010876693 & 1010984288 & 1010967918 & 1010926974 & 1010931104 & 1010922436 & 1010975984 & 1010942746 & 1010879443 & 1010963442 & 1010949653 & 1010920686 & 1010950924 & 1010954975 & 1010919343\\
1010916919 & 1010893135 & 1010932617 & 1010931028 & 1010953514 & 1010946336 & 1010874006 & 1010949886 & 1010946408 & 1010919972 & 1010933623 & 1010944638 & 1010918804 & 1010910417 & 1010948180 & 1010924548\\
1010952714 & 1010910696 & 1010967418 & 1010924316 & 1010901209 & 1010917153 & 1010927221 & 1010922785 & 1010913319 & 1010961108 & 1010965367 & 1010923774 & 1010956655 & 1010932756 & 1010943145 & 1010959839\\
1010902057 & 1010937300 & 1010894215 & 1010954705 & 1010946686 & 1010919565 & 1010960715 & 1010962030 & 1010930489 & 1010937969 & 1010923175 & 1010924144 & 1010967562 & 1010974277 & 1010937684 & 1010895821\\
1010925188 & 1010953235 & 1010897286 & 1010977090 & 1010924147 & 1010947516 & 1010923802 & 1010943058 & 1010903071 & 1010904599 & 1010940461 & 1010949700 & 1010987516 & 1010938254 & 1010896618 & 1010980031\\
1010933359 & 1010929155 & 1010903726 & 1010921884 & 1010947029 & 1010950279 & 1010937089 & 1010934314 & 1010925524 & 1010895195 & 1010897302 & 1010901076 & 1010961624 & 1010942690 & 1010923176 & 1010928225\\
1010871220 & 1010904368 & 1010967581 & 1010941080 & 1010879547 & 1010954499 & 1011001377 & 1010912651 & 1010895522 & 1010943091 & 1010952233 & 1010914450 & 1010926001 & 1010905592 & 1010928990 & 1010975526\\
1011009526 & 1010942261 & 1010954044 & 1011011959 & 1010940244 & 1010955991 & 1010942391 & 1010895238 & 1010910814 & 1010899109 & 1010948671 & 1010973726 & 1010939240 & 1010987253 & 1010899653 & 1010937320\\
1010966670 & 1010950801 & 1010947870 & 1010955096 & 1010922876 & 1010921403 & 1010908364 & 1010973666 & 1010937391 & 1010889507 & 1010916100 & 1010917292 & 1010969773 & 1010908227 & 1010912085 & 1011023901\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Doing the math on those numbers I compute a Chi-Square test statistic of around 244.393. I further find that

$$p = \Pr[\chi^2_{255} > 244.393] \approx 0.672515$$

This is a surprisingly awful result for the huge amount of input data and very good underlying CSPRNG. Does this mean that with around 33% probability the numbers are not following a uniform distribution?

What mistake am I making in my thinking and is there a way to correct it or choose a better approach to the analysis I'm conducting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numbers you've provided are correct, I've independently checked that your $244.393$ number and the probability $0.67$ are correct.

Note that to reject the null hypothesis ("the generator generates numbers uniformly") at a 5% level, we need $p < 0.05$, i.e. a very large chi-squared statistic. For any value of $p$ larger than 0.05, we say "we do not have sufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis." Even though your chi-squared value is moderately large, the test suggests that it is still reasonable that it may have arisen by chance, rather than from non-uniformity in the generator.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense. I was thinking about this the wrong way.